# Peculiar behavior with a Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

```
scala> sealed trait Gender
defined trait Gender

scala> case object Male extends Gender
defined module Male

scala> case object Female extends Gender
defined module Female

scala> Map(Male -> Male, Female -> Female, Male -> Female, Female -> Male)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Product with Gender,Product with Gender] =
        Map((Male,Female), (Female,Male))
```

Why in the above code, the type of `res2` is `Map[Product with Gender, Product with Gender]` instead of `Map[Gender, Gender]`? And why of the four entries I supplied to map, only two got added?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) `Product` is the lowest-level superclass of both `Male` and `Female`.  This is because all case classes extend `Product`. Both have trait `Gender`, which Scala recognizes, so it includes that too.  This is Scala's best guess for type inference because it is the most specific type inferable (`Map[Gender,Gender]` is more general).  If you want the type to be `Map[Gender,Gender]`, you can tell it that explicitly:

```
scala> val x: Map[Gender,Gender] = Map(Male -> Male, Female -> Female, Male -> Female, Female -> Male)
x: Map[Gender,Gender] = Map(Male -> Female, Female -> Male)
```

2) The nature of a Map is that it has only *one* value for each key.  When you add `Male -> Male` you are mapping `Male` to `Male`.  When you add `Male -> Female` you are *overwriting* the original mapping so that now `Male` maps to `Female`.  If you want to have all of these mappings, then it's probably easier to just to a list of pairs since that doesn't enforce any uniqueness constraints.